# Git : Why Do I See Previously Committed Changes?

Tags: git

I made a mistake with my git repositories(edited files from the "main" one), and I had to use "git push -f" to force my "main" repository to accept my local revision. I went back to my remote main repository and did a git status.

I see that the changes to be committed are old and do not reflect my actual local repository status (the one that pushed -f). So, if I do a git commit on the main, it works fine, but the two repositories differ.

The situation is not resolved since a new standard git push shows an error:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
```

How can this be resolved so that my main repos has the same content as my local copy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should normally not do a `git push` to a non-bare repository, i.e. a repository which has a working copy attached. The reason is that git push does not update the working directory (it can't reliably do this), and thus either the HEAD gets out of sync with its branch, or out of sync with its working copy.

If you want to push to some repository, let this be a bare repository without working copy. Otherwise, use `fetch` and `pull` to get the changes to your repository (used at this repository itself).

Comment: I'm previously a subversion user and dont have much experience with git, that's why i made this mistake. The thing is that i created a remote repos that would be my main one, from a copy of my code with git init. Do you think i should just recreate the repository in my remote server ? Making it a bare one ? Btw, how does a bare one work ? It has sort of an internal database that tracks file changes, but does not allow you to edit them directly ?

Comment: A "bare repository" is the thing which you would in svn simply call a repository - i.e. the thing which sits on the server (too simplified, of course).  The non-base repositories are used for your working copies (but in git they contain the whole history, too).

Comment: If you now have all the code (with all the revisions you want) in your local repository, you can recreate your "main" one with `git clone --bare` (if you can access your local repository from there). Otherwise, do a new `git init --bare` and then use `git push` from your local one.

Comment: ahh ok i understand it this way :)